# REPEAT an UPDATE SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join, repeat

I have several elements inside a tree (Jquery Nested Sortable). In this tree there are two possible types. When I drag a node into another node which have a different type I want to update the item and its childs to its new parent. I got it working with some php code but I don't want to perform to much sql-updates. So I decided to let the database do it's work.

I'm trying to repeat an update function in sql. But I can't get it to work. I hope someone can help me:

```
REPEAT 
UPDATE elements a, elements b 
    SET a.type=b.type 
    WHERE a.parent_id=b.id 
    AND a.type<>b.type 
    AND a.parent_id<>0
UNTIL ROW_COUNT()=0 
END REPEAT;
```

The update statement works like a charm but only once. I want the query to run again and again until no changes (row_count) is found.

--- UPDATE:
A reaction to the comment from WojtusJ
I tried the following inside the SQL window in PhpMyAdmin:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS UpdateElements()

CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateElements();
BEGIN
DECLARE cnt;
REPEAT 
    SELECT count(*) AS cnt INTO @cnt 
    FROM elements AS a 
        JOIN elements AS b 
            ON (a.parent_id=b.id AND a.type<>b.type AND a.parent_id<>0);

    UPDATE elements a, elements b 
        SET a.type=b.type 
    WHERE a.parent_id=b.id 
        AND a.type<>b.type 
        AND a.parent_id<>0;
UNTIL @cnt=0 END REPEAT;
END

CALL UpdateElements()
```

Comment: Why have you put this in a loop? just let the database do its work.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Propagate `type` from some root node to all of its descendents until it encounters a matching `type`?

Comment: I have several elements inside a tree (Jquery Nested Sortable). In this tree there are two possible types. When I drag a node into another node which have a different type I want to update the item and its childs to its new parent. I got it working with some php code but I don't want to perform to much sql-updates. So I decided to let the database do it's work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken the usage of ROW_COUNT() function here is wrong. You probably should check if there are any changes left with other statement. Try this:

```
DECLARE cnt INT;
REPEAT 
    SELECT count(*) AS cnt INTO @cnt 
    FROM elements AS a 
        JOIN elements AS b 
            ON (a.parent_id=b.id AND a.type<>b.type AND a.parent_id<>0);

    UPDATE elements a, elements b 
        SET a.type=b.type 
    WHERE a.parent_id=b.id 
        AND a.type<>b.type 
        AND a.parent_id<>0;
UNTIL @cnt=0 END REPEAT;
```

EDIT:
Of course you should put the above code within "CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name BEGIN ... END" and than use the CALL statement to run it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I pasted your code inside Sql inside my PhpMyAdmin. It gave this error:

SQL-query:

DECLARE cnt INT;

MySQL returned: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE cnt INT' at line 1

Comment: MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual says: Error: 1064 SQLSTATE: 42000 (ER_PARSE_ERROR)

Message: %s near '%s' at line %d ?????

Comment: Have you put the whole thing within CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name BEGIN ... END statements? After that you should call it using CALL statement.

Comment: WojtusJ, thanks for your reaction: I've entered the exact code that I put inside the phpMyAdmin in my question, see above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the reply's. I didn't know how to create routines.

inside the SQL window in phpMyAdmin I did the following (thanks to WojtusJ)

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS UpdateElements $$

CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateElements ()
BEGIN
DECLARE cnt INT;
REPEAT 
    SELECT count(*) AS cnt INTO @cnt 
    FROM elements AS a 
    JOIN elements AS b 
        ON (a.parent_id=b.id AND a.type<>b.type AND a.parent_id<>0);

UPDATE elements a, elements b 
    SET a.type=b.type 
WHERE a.parent_id=b.id 
    AND a.type<>b.type 
    AND a.parent_id<>0;
UNTIL @cnt=0 END REPEAT;
END $$
```

Change the delimiter to $$ (just below the SQL window)

After this routine is entered it can be called inside a new blank phpMyAdmin SQL window (or inside your php script)

```
CALL UpdateElements
```